# Alert on concurrent thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

In my application I'm calling a method asynchronously by a button press. The screen segues to a different view controller which is a table view.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask  *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request 
        completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:location];
            NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                             options:0 
                                                               error:&error];
            self.yearBucket = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSDictionary * dict in array) {
                Year *year = [[Year alloc ]init];
                year.yearName =[dict objectForKey:@"Year"];
                year.speeches = [dict objectForKey:@"Speeches"];
                [self.yearBucket addObject:year];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
    ...
```

The problem is that the UI moves into a blank table view, since the data takes time to load. How can I display and alert view on the next screen that dynamically displays the loading of the data and can is dismissed as soon as the view refreshes back to the main thread.

Comment: I usually create my own dialog, show it on the main thread before starting any download, then [after a while] start the downloading process, usually in a separate thread, and periodically, on the main thread, update the progress bar. You are using NSURLSessionDownloadTask so you can get progress by setting a delegate on your NSURLSessionDownloadTask. Then you will get a message with your download progress -URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:

Comment: take a look: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=progress+bar

Comment: What do you mean with "next screen"? Isn't the table view referred to by `self.tableView` THAT view which should display something like a spinner or progress bar up until data is eventually available? (respectively the UIViewController embedding this table view, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you display an [MVProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) on your view whilst you load the data and then perform a `[tableview reloadData]` in order to update the data shown in the table.

You should probably also display a network activity indicator. This is simply good practise when network connectivity is occurring. I presume if your app relies on an internet connection you are checking for connectivity before allowing the user to begin a request?